# Spring MVC populate @RequestParam Map<String, String>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, data-binding, parameters

I have the following method in my Spring MVC @Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testUrl(@RequestParam(value="test") Map<String, String> test) {   
    (...)
}
```

I call it like this :

```
http://myUrl?test[A]=ABC&test[B]=DEF
```

However the "test" RequestParam variable is always null

What do I have to do in order to populate "test" variable ?

Comment: Did you resolve this? If so can you post your answer?

Comment: Sorry for this late answer, but I can't help anyway. It's been over a year I worked in the project, and from what I remember I couldn't find a viable solution, so I just dropped this part and found an alternative way to do what I was supposed to do. Steel waiting for a solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As detailed here
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html

If the method parameter is Map or MultiValueMap and a parameter name is not specified, then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names and values.

So you would change your definition like this.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testUrl(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) 
{   
  (...)
}
```

And in your parameters if you called the url http://myUrl?A=ABC&B=DEF

You would have in your method

```
parameters.get("A");
parameters.get("B");
```

Comment: I don't need to retrieve all the request parameters, that's why I added (value="test"). And even when retrieving them like that, the url "test[A]=ABC&test[B]=DEF" gives me "test[A]" as key and not just "A"

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new class that contains the map that should be populated by Spring and then use that class as a parameter of your `@RequestMapping` annotated method.

In your example create a new class

```
public static class Form {
   private Map<String, String> test;
   // getters and setters
}
```

Then you can use `Form` as a parameter in your method.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testUrl(Form form) {
  // use values from form.getTest()
}
```

Comment: This should be selected as the correct answer. I faced a similar problem. See my answer for additional information.

Comment: This will force a request body contained of json. GET is the wrong mapping here.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar situation where the client sends *two* groups of variable parameters. Let's call these groups `foo` and `bar`. A request could look like:

```
GET /search?page=2&size=10&foo[x]=aaa&foo[y]=bbb&bar[z]=ccc
```

I wanted to map these parameters to two distinct maps. Something like:

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public Page<...> search(Pageable pageable,
        @RequestParam(...) Map<String, String> foo,
        @RequestParam(...) Map<String, String> bar) {
    ...
}
```

`@RequestParam` didn't work for me, too. Instead I created a Model class with two fields of type `Map<>` matching the query parameter names `foo` and `bar` (`@Data` is `lombok.Data`).

```
@Data
public static class FooBar {
    Map<String, String> foo;
    Map<String, String> bar;
}
```

My controller code has changed to:

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public Page<...> search(Pageable pageable, FooBar fooBar) {
    ...
}
```

When requesting `GET /search?page=2&size=10&foo[x]=aaa&foo[y]=bbb&bar[z]=ccc` Spring instantiated the Maps and filled `fooBar.getFoo()` with keys/values `x`/`aaa` and `y`/`bbb` and `fooBar.getBar()` with `z`/`ccc`.

Answer (score 2):

Spring doesn't have default conversion strategy from multiple parameters with the same name to HashMap. It can, however, convert them easily to List, array or Set.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testset", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testSet(@RequestParam(value = "test") Set<String> test) {

        return "success";
    }
```

I tested with postman like `http://localhost:8080/mappings/testset?test=ABC&test=DEF`

You will see set having data, [ABC, DEF]

Comment: I don't need a List but a Map. So in other words I have to create a custom editor ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question needs to be considered from different points of view.

1. first part:

as is mentioned in the title of the question, is how to have `Map<String, String>` as `@RequestParam`.

Consider this endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/map")
public ResponseEntity getData(@RequestParam Map<String, String> allParams) {
    String str = Optional.ofNullable(allParams.get("first")).orElse(null);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(str);
}
```

you can call that via:

```
http://<ip>:<port>/child/map?first=data1&second=data2
```

then when you debug your code, you will get these values:

```
> allParams (size = 2)
    > first = data1
    > second = data2
```

and the response of the requested url will be `data1`.

---

2. second part:

as your requested url shows (you have also said that in other answers' comments) ,you need an `array` to be passed by url.

consider this endpoint:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> getData (@RequestParam("test") Long[] testId,
                                  @RequestParam("notTest") Long notTestId)
```

to call this API and pass proper values, you need to pass parameters in this way:

```
?test=1&test=2&notTest=3
```

all `test` values are reachable via `test[0]` or `test[1]` in your code.

---

3. third part:

have another look on requested url parameters, like: `test[B]`

putting `brackets` (or `[` `]`) into url is not usually possible. you have to put equivalent `ASCII` code with `%` sign.

for example `[` is equal to `%5B` and `]` is equal to `%5D`.

as an example, `test[0]` would be `test%5B0%5D`.

more `ASCII` codes on: https://ascii.cl/

Answer (score 1):

you can use MultiValueMap

> MultiValueMap<String, String>

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testUrl(@RequestParam(value="test") MultiValueMap<String, String> test) {   
    (...)
}
```

and while testing don't use test[A],test[B]. just use it as stated below.

```
http://myUrl?test=ABC&test=DEF
```

test result will be in below format when you print it.

> test = {[ABC, DEF]}