# creating a custom query in Springboot mongodb(using crudRepository)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to Create custom query which will depend on number of Fields will get from @RequestParam Like

```
public List<User> method(
  @RequestParam("key") String []key,
  @RequestParam("value") String [] value){}
```

Then I have to create a query in Service layer according to number of element I'll get in key and value

For example in first array(in key) element is "UserName" then in value array I'll get (value of username)

In these arrays, the number of fields will be dynamic. After that I have to pass that whole query String in Repository of Springboot & retrieve data from mongodb database.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: @secretsuperstar  i want to genrate the query and want to pass. i don't think that link is helpfull . but thanks sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would use a map instead of two arrays to map the request params.

For dynamic queries you have to use `query criteria` or `HQL`.

Then based on the map entries I would build the `query criteria` from `JPA`.

There is already a lot of material on how to build a [criteria](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-search-language-spring-jpa-criteria).

Comment: can you tell me example  of query criteria for this problem or code snippet with atleaset 2 key value pair ,Because i'm totally new in Mongo & query criteria

Comment: And i thing JPA is only for Rdbms not for NoSql

Comment: query criteria and mongo db https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb

Comment: map as request param is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47418489/spring-mvc-populate-requestparam-mapstring-string

Comment: can anyone tell me logic as in code of this because i'm not able to get the solution of this problem

Comment: dude, you have all the material in the comments. First you need to map the request params to a map. Then you will end up in the repository. You will iterate over the map entries. And based on the entries you will create the query criteria. That's all :).