# My request is not able to accept a Map data object and throws 400 bad request

Tags: java, spring

My `Map<String, Object>` parameter is throwing a `400 bad request error` with the following message, `Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'data'` and I am not sure why?

In my postman, I go to `Body` then `form-data` and I place `data` under `Key` then I place the following value `{ "key": "value" }`.

My model with the request parameter and controller:

```
public class RequestModel {

   @Schema(type = "object")
   private Map<String, Object> data;

   private MultipartFile file;
   private String requestId;
   private String date;

}

public class Controller {
   
   @PostMapping(value = "/send", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, consumes = {
        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
   public ResponseEntity<Response> send(@ModelAttribute final RequestModel model) {
      var response = service.send(model);
      return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
   }

}
```

---

All my other parameters is able to get pass fine, except for the `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems similar to [Java_Spring: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'paramsMap'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60765875/java-spring-failed-to-convert-property-value-of-type-java-lang-string-to-requ)

Perhaps try changing how you're sending the body by changing
var response = service.send(model);

To more closely resemble the json format something like:
{ "paramsMap": { "Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2" } }:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try with @RequestPart annotation :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/send", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<Response> send(@RequestPart Map<String, Object> data){}
```

Or if you can consume json then :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/send", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<Response> send(@RequestBody RequestModelDto data){}
```

Comment: I can't use RequestPart because I need to send a file within the api call

Comment: "@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file" /  "@RequestPart("files") List<MultipartFile> files" or cast item from your "Map<String, Object> data". You can also debug your request to explore "data"